# How to establish a main page by means of htaccess in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to establish a page of the site as the main one through htaccess, since in wordpress, within settings - reading does not appear.

I would like it to be redirected to domain.com/Business and if possible that / Business is hidden or not shown. If there is a plugin that does this, I would appreciate it. This is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in your `wp-config.php`

Just put this:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```

Place it right after the opening `<?php`